# Python print returns <function newsearch at 0x7fb5cfb96cb0> instead of answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have run across this a few times. I expect an output such as a list or a boolean of True or False and instead just get something like:

```
<function newsearch at 0x7fb5cfb96cb0>  

<function search at 0x7f672e90bc20>
```

The actual problem I am having is a homework problem so I can't post the code until tomorrow, but occasionally I run across then when trying to print out the results of a function. Why does this happen?

I can post exact code tomorrow and update question if it isn't possible to answer without it. I don't want to break the honor code, but would like to know if there is a general reason why this happens so I can learn from it.

Comment: you need to actually call the function. With parentheses...

Comment: You can print the function `print(lambda x: x)`, or the result of applying a function `print((lambda x: x)(3))`

Comment: Excellent. I see where it is messing up. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This question is incredibly vague, but the answer is that instead of calling the function, you are referencing the function's address. You need to add parentheses to the call. In python `a.method` is not the same thing as `a.method()`. So you need to use `a.method()`.

Comment: That fixed it. Sorry for being vague. I am trying to learn without breaking the honor code. Stack Overflow is actually suggested as a resource, you just can't ask someone to fix the exact issue just use it to figure out generally what is wrong. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @answrseeker Stack overflow is a great resource for learning how to code (I use it for a lot of questions I have), but the type of questions we answer on here generally show some code example, and are beyond just looking at the error message. For the future, try to show something similar to your code with problems and we can better help.